# can a bare metal targeted binary be executed on a musllibc linux

Tags: gcc, arm, cross-compiling, arm64, bare-metal

my binary file compiled use toolchain from  https://developer.arm.com/-/media/Files/downloads/gnu-a/10.3-2021.07/binrel/gcc-arm-10.3-2021.07-x86_64-arm-none-eabi.tar.xz,

with link flag:

```
-lstdc++ -Wl,-z,relro,-z,now -pass-exit-codes -lm -Wall '--specs=rdimon.specs' -lrdimon '-mcpu=cortex-a72.cortex-a53' -mthumb -static
```

compiled successfully, but when I execute this file on my openwrt router, it said:

**Segmentation fault.**

I think a bare-metal binary can also be executed on a linux system, it doesn't have any relationships with any os, only with a cpu model. Am I right?

**FYI:**

my chip model was rockchip 3389, armv8, 4 cortex-a72 core and 2 cortex-a53 core, run under aarch64 mode

Comment: after googled a lot, it seems need provide start and end code to start a bare-metal binary, but I don't know how to provide these code, and where to find these code, is there any post or example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. *I think a bare-metal binary can also be executed on a linux system, it doesn't have any relationships with any os, only with a cpu model. Am I right?*
   No, you are not.
2. If your SoC has A72 and A53 cores, you are not using the right compiler: if you were writing bare-metal programs for it, you would have to use the  [aarch64-none-elf](https://developer.arm.com/-/media/Files/downloads/gnu-a/10.3-2021.07/binrel/gcc-arm-10.3-2021.07-x86_64-aarch64-none-elf.tar.xz) toolchain, and not the [arm-none-eabi](https://developer.arm.com/-/media/Files/downloads/gnu-a/10.3-2021.07/binrel/gcc-arm-10.3-2021.07-x86_64-arm-none-eabi.tar.xz) one,
3. OpenWRT is a Linux operating system: on a `glibc`-based Linux system, you would use the [aarch64-none-linux-gnu](https://developer.arm.com/-/media/Files/downloads/gnu-a/10.3-2021.07/binrel/gcc-arm-10.3-2021.07-x86_64-aarch64-none-linux-gnu.tar.xz) toolchain, but when targeting a `musl-libc`-based system, you should for example use a [aarch64-linux-musl](https://musl.cc/aarch64-linux-musl-cross.tgz) toolchain.

Comment: some post said if add start and end assembly code to bare-metal binary file, then binary file can be executed on linux, am I right? https://balau82.wordpress.com/2010/02/28/hello-world-for-bare-metal-arm-using-qemu/

Comment: https://balau82.wordpress.com/2010/02/28/hello-world-for-bare-metal-arm-using-qemu/ this post seems only run on a qemu, I guess qemu is just a bare metal, not have a OS, but why a bare-metal binary file cannot be excuted on linux? @Frant

Comment: @xiedeacc: : 1) bare-metal means not running on an operating system, therefore a program executing on Linux does not qualify as a bare-metal program. 2) There are two different flavours of qemu: `qemu-user` and `qemu-system`: `qemu-arm` allows you to run, say, arm linux programs, on a x86_64 Linux system: the arm code will be emulated by qemu but the linux system calls will be provided by the host operating system. `qemu-system-arm` allows emulating a complete virtual Single Board  Computer, and this is the version Francesco Balducci is using in its Balau's blog article you are referencing.